# Protected Observable re-renders entire viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js

I have an issue using the protectedObservable custom binding below found at this link.

http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html

The protected observable is nested within 3 child templates.

```
<select class="select-teams bracket-select" data-bind="value: divisionTeamId, options: $root.teams, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: ' - Teams - '"></select>
```

When this isn't a protected observable the viewmodel doesn't rerender itself.  When it is protected the template rerenders and it loses it's initial value.  Any clue why this is going on?

```
self.divisionTeamId = ko.protectedObservable(undefined);
```

Custom Binding

```
ko.protectedObservable = function (initialValue) {

        var _actualValue = ko.observable(initialValue),
        _tempValue = initialValue;

        var result = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return _actualValue();
            },
            write: function (newValue) {
                _tempValue = newValue;
            }
        });

        result.commit = function () {
            if (_tempValue !== _actualValue()) {
                _actualValue(_tempValue);
            }
        };

        result.reset = function () {
            _actualValue.valueHasMutated();
            _tempValue = _actualValue();
        };

        return result;
    };
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found that removing the stopBinding fixed the issue.

```
<div data-bind="stopBinding: true">
    <div id="bracket-namespace">
          .....
    </div>
</div>

    app.members.bracket.init = function (options) {
        viewModel = new ViewModel(options);

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("bracket-namespace"));
    };

ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function () {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you put something in jsFiddle?  Maybe a simplified sample.  There are a number of ways to tweak the protected observable, if necessary.

Comment: Also, you will always want to put the `value` binding after the `options` binding in a select.  If the options are not already present, then the value binding will believe that your choice is invalid.

Comment: I will try to create a Fiddle but the page contains alot of logic and html so Im not sure I can replicate it unless I replicate the whole page.  I tried to put the value at the end of the binding, but same deal.

Comment: I just couldn't replicate this in JFiddle.  I attached a screenshot of the callstack.  When I hit reset it calls valueHasMutated on the actual value, but then goes down the line and calls html.update which is dynamic HTML.  This shouldn't be reevaluated and re-rendered.

Comment: Looks like I found the issue from the Update above.  Any clue why this would happen?

Comment: Not sure.  Doesn't seem like it could be related, but hard to tell.  I would like to know the root cause of your issue.  I wish that it would show up for you in jsFiddle.  Maybe you can send me something with it not working?

Comment: Does it fix the problem if you try your code with the latest development version of Knockout? If you don't want to build it, you can get it [here](http://bestware.us/knockout/latest/knockout-latest.debug.js). Also try newest version and change `_tempValue = _actualValue();` to `_tempValue = _actualValue.peek();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the stopBinding:true and it fixed it.  So I took a different route with populating the dynamic HTML since I still wanted to use stopBinding:true.  I explicitly populated the dynamic HTML container that is filled during an ajax call.  So instead of setting it with the "html" binding of the container element, I used jQuery $(container).html(...) to populate it.  My final implementation is below.  The stopBinding either uses the parent VM or a new one depending on the ajax page stopBinding property.

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix" data-bind="stopBinding: members.stopBinding, container: {}">  
     @RenderBody()
</div>
```